# Prove/disprove that $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }a_nb_nx^n<\infty$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $R_1>0$ and $R_2=\infty$ be the convergence radius of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$ respectively.

Prove or provide a counter example:

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }a_nb_nx^n$ is convergent for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

I assume this one is a proof, but I don't know how to start it.

Any tips will be amazing!

Thanks!

Comment: Hint : try to show that $a_nb_n r^n \to 0$ for every $r>0$ using the fact that $a_n (R/2)^n\to 0$ and $b_n\rho^n \to 0$ for every $\rho >0$.

Comment: You can also compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty} |x| |a_n|^{1/n} |b_n|^{1/n}=|x| \frac{1}{R_1} 0 = 0,$$ meaning the radius of convergence is infinite.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your approaches..

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true. if you prefer using hints instead, you can just read portions of the proof.

Let $0<\left|x_{0}\right|<R_{1}$.
 We know that $\displaystyle{{\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x_{0}^{n}}}$ converges, which implies $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}x_{0}^{n}=0}$ that is, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge N$ we have:
$$\left|a_{n}x_{0}^{n}\right|<1\;\;\;\left(*\right)$$
Now let $x\in \mathbb R$. then:
$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}b_{n}x^{n}\right|=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}b_{n}\left(\frac{x}{x_{0}}\right)^{n}\cdot x_{0}^{n}\right|\underset{\left(*\right)}{\le}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left|b_{n}\left(\frac{x}{x_{0}}\right)^{n}\right|\underset{R_{2}=\infty}{<}\infty$$

Comment: Thank you Guy! That really helps! :)

Comment: I'm glad it did :)

Comment: Quick question, why did you use $x_0$, you can just say that $|a_nx^n|<1$, and in the end $\sum |a_nb_nx^n| \le \sum |b_n| < \infty$

Comment: I couldn't say that as the power series with $a_n$  doesn't converge for every $x$, so I had to choose a specific $x_0$ for which it does.

Comment: Oh you are right! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you will be able to help me here if you have some time :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165037/contradiction-to-sum-n-0-infty-n-a-nx-1-x-0n-1-is-convergent  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ofc but I see you already got a quick answer