# Contradiction to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_n(x_1-x_0)^{n-1}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

I have a limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n|x_1-x_0|^n \ne 0$, and I want to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_n(x_1-x_0)^{n-1}$ is divergent.

We also know that $|x_1-x_0|>R \ge 0$.

I assumed towards a contradiction that the series converges, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n (x_1-x_0)^{n-1}=0$.

So after some cosmetic changes, we get that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n(x_1-x_0)^n=0$.

So I separeted in to 2 case:

If $x_1-x_0>0$, than we get an easy contradiction.

If $x_1-x_0<0$ we get that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \cdot |x_1-x_0|^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \cdot (-1)^n(x_1-x_0)^n$

But I do not know how to get a contradiction here.

Any help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n|x_1-x_0|^n\ne0,\tag1$$then$$\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n|x_1-x_0|^{n-1}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{|x_1-x_0|}|a_n||x_1-x_0|^n=\infty,$$due to $(1)$ and to the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{|x_1-x_0|}=\infty$. So, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n(x_1-x_0)^{n-1}$ diverges.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm just curious, what if $(1) \to -\infty$  or does not exists?

Comment: Simply consider the limit supremum $S$ of the sequence $\{|a_n||x_1-x_0|^n\}$. This is not $0$. Which implies that there exists a sub sequence  $|a_{n_k}||x_1-x_0|^{n_k}$ converging to $S$ (if $S$ is infinite, then this subsequence diverges). Now $n_k|a_{n_k}||x_1-x_0|^{n_k}$ goes to infinity!